# Can you use "cin" with string?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I was taught that you have to use `gets(str)` to input a string and not `cin`. However I can use `cin` just fine in the program below. Can someone tell me if you can use `cin` or not. Sorry for my bad English. The program lets you insert 5 names and then print those names to the screen.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char **p = new char *[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *(p + i) = new char[255];
    } //make a 2 dimensional array of strings

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char n[255] = "";
        cout << "insert names: ";
        cin >> n; //how i can use cin here to insert the string to an array??
        strcpy(p[i], n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << p[i] << endl; //print the names
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try names that consist of fistname and lastname? For example "Peter Fish" ?

Comment: Don't use `gets`, it's  a deprecated function and for good reason: *"The function provides no means to prevent buffer overflow of the destination array, given sufficiently long input string. std::gets was deprecated in C++11 and removed from C++14. std::fgets can be used instead."*

Answer (score 14):

You can indeed use something like

```
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
```

but the reading from the stream will stop on the first white space, so a name of the form "Bathsheba Everdene" will stop just after "Bathsheba".

An alternative is

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

which will read the whole line.

This has advantages over using a `char[]` buffer, as you don't need to worry about the size of the buffer, and the `std::string` will take care of all the memory management for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use ws (whitespace) in getline() like getline(cin>>ws, name);
If numeric input is before the string then due to whitespace the first string input will be ignored. Therefore use ws like getline(cin>>ws, name);

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main(){
    int id=0;   
    string name, address;

    cout <<"Id? "; cin>>id;

    cout <<"Name? ";
    getline(cin>>ws, name);

    cout <<"Address? ";
    getline(cin>>ws, address);

   cout <<"\nName: " <<name <<"\nAddress: " <<address;
}
```

Comment: For reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws