Reading Writing Files in Fstream C++
I am writing a basic todo app to read and write notes to a text file. The problem with my code is that it doesn't read or write spaces in my file, like if i add a todo like "hello world", only hello is written to the file
Here is My Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool running = true;
    string input;
    string output;

    while (running) {
        fstream writer("todo.txt");
        // Getiing The Input Of The User
        cout << "What would you like to do (type 'help' for help)  \n";
        cin >> input;

        // The Help Function
        if (input == "help") {
            cout << "  Adding a todo(add) \n  Removing a todo(remove) \n  Viewing Todos(view)  \n  Killing the program(exit0)\n";
        }
        //For Closing The App
        else if (input == "exit0") {
            writer.close();
            return 0;
        }
        //Adding a ToDo
        else if (input == "add") {
            writer.seekg(0, fstream::end);
            cout << "What is your todo/note for today \n";
            cin >> input;
            writer << input << endl;
            writer.close();
        }
        else if (input == "view") {
            while (getline(writer, output)) {
                // Output the text from the file
                cout << endl << output;
            }
        }
    }
}


you are doing too much at once. Its not writing to the file that has an issue, but reading user input. Why do you use getline in one place but then cin in another?

cin >> input; reads up to the first whitespace character into input. If you typed Jon Doe input would contain: Jon and Doe would be left in the buffer. See this answer for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63519945/487892 and also be careful mixing cin with getline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Baby-steps... Start with basic input and output (with std::cin and std::cout), use both formatted input with >> and std::getline. Learn about the differences, and what happens when you mix them, and with different types of input. Then once you got all that working, learn about file-streams without involving any user input or output. Just write to a file, in different ways, in one program. In another program learn how to read from a file. Once you're comfortable with all of the above, put it together, bit by bit, for your exercise or assignment.

The problem is that cin only reads until it reaches a space or end of line. To get input strings that contain spaces you will need to use the getline function instead.
replace cin >> input;
with getline(cin, input);
